# How work around java.lang.verifyerror in Android

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I have an app which works perfect in all 4.x devices, but now I have a report of the app not working on a samsung_gt (advance) android 2.3.6. Here is the trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.VerifyError: com.bamobile.fdtks.activities.MainActivity
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1024)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3770)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have the latest support jar (v4) and have already patched the gson library in case the phone is already using it. The problem seems to be the the support lib. Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you post the source code of MainActivity?

Comment: @user3431672 is a Fragment Activity. which holds a FragmentManagerAdaper and durin the call to the getItem of the adapter it crushes

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, you are using a class which is not a part of androd 2.3.6. You should really post the code further for other people to help.  If you feel that your code cannot be pasted, create a sample project recreating the issue and then you can share that code.

Comment: As mentioned the problem is with the fragment frameqwork of the support package, and the jar is in the proyect.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of `java.lang.VerifyError` is having a class that uses methods that are not available on the version of Android where the app is running.

Based on your stacktrace, it seems that `com.bamobile.fdtks.activities.MainActivity` is using a method that is not available on Android 2.3.6, hence the "verification error" that you're seeing.

To fix it, change the `minSdkVersion` and of your app to `9` or `10` (Android 2.3.6) and look for errors/warnings about unsupported methods for that version of Android. You can also change (temporarily) both `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `9` to force the compiler to fail when you use methods that are not found in Gingerbread devices.