# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: android

Guys I am getting the below error in RunTime, what is the root cause of this error?

```
java.lang.VerifyError: appPackageName at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2698)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5457)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122666/how-work-around-java-lang-verifyerror-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your support and answers, may be your answers are right but in my case I used **extra variables** in one **method** while I was testing, so this exception appeared. Now I get rid of **redundant** things in my code and it start working. It may help others.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using or accessing something which is simply supported in higher android SDK, as the error shows here `java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)`.
I happened to have the same kind of VerifyError while I was using `String.isEmplty();`. It seems you have same kind of problem as the message showing error in `java.lang.Class`

**Thrown when the "verifier" detects that a class file, though well formed, contains some sort of internal inconsistency or security problem.**

Here is official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/VerifyError.html#VerifyError())

Comment: Thanks @junaid for your answer but in my case I wasn't using anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible causes:**

1. You might have imported something which is using different support v4/v7 library version.
2. You are targeting something from a higher SDK version. In that case, update your support repository and SDK build version.

Comment: Thanks @Prokash for your answer but in my case I wasn't using anything like this.